# How to refer to last argument in m4 macro

Tags: macros, m4

How does one refer to the last argument in a given list of arguments in an m4 macro? I have a requirement to pull the last argument and generate macro expansion based on that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not particularly elegant, but it works:

```
define(`last',`ifelse(`$#',`0',`',`$#',`1',`$1',`last(shift($@))')')dnl
last(foo,bar,baz)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# more elegant solution:
changequote([,])
define([LEN], [$#])
define([LAST], [pushdef([$0], $LEN($@))$0($@)[]popdef([$0])])
define([LAST_BUT_ONE], [pushdef([$0], $decr(LEN($@)))$0($@)[]popdef([$0])])

LAST(foo, bar, baz)

LAST_BUT_ONE(foo, bar, baz)
```